# Rails 3 and ar_extensions: undefined method attribute_condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, deprecated

I kept getting this error in my Rails app after upgrading to Rails 3.

```
>> u.sent_messages
NoMethodError: undefined method `attribute_condition' for #Class:0x105523f18
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/finders.rb:79:in `sanitize_sql_from_hash'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/finders.rb:55:in `each_pair'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/finders.rb:55:in `sanitize_sql_from_hash'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/finders.rb:27:in `sanitize_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `sanitized_conditions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:105:in `conditions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:103:in `construct_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1492:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1492:in `sent_messages'
    from (irb):36
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:488
```

Turns out I was still using the ar_extensions Gem from http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/arext. For one thing they have a successor, for another there is a bulk insert option in ActiveRecord now which might be worth checking out (using Model.create([hash1, hash2, hash3, ...])).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ar-extensions is only for use in Rails 2.x. For Rails 3.x you should use the activerecord-import gem. It has the same import API.

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: True, thank you. However, again I had to patch PostgreSQL to allow bulk imports (multiple rows in one INSERT clause). Since I insert thousands of rows in one go, this is a must for performance. Is there a specific reason why this is not the default?

Comment: Jens, I don't use PostgreSQL so it uses the fallback mechanism of single insert statements. I'd love to look over your patch to get this in activerecord-import.

Comment: module ActiveRecord # :nodoc:
     module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
      class PostgreSQLAdapter # :nodoc:
       def supports_import?
         true
       end
      end
     end
    end

Comment: Jens, the #supports_import? method is used so you can use the #import API. If someone were to implement optimized PostgreSQL support you wouldn't have to change your code, it would just be faster. #supports_import? has nothing to do with the database adapter being optimized, just if it supports the API.

Comment: This might be true, however, without this line, "Foo.import_without_validations_or_callbacks csv_array" will create thousands of separate INSERT statements, and with this statement, it will create only a few dozen (albeit large) INSERT statements.

Comment: is there any alternative gem for providing the _ne and similar symbol extensions within Rails 3 AR?

Comment: NewAlexandria, not that I am aware of.